# Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Getting error when running `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`. Here is the error log:

```
module.js:442
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Comment: one is global version, one is local version. when webpack-dev-server, local version is used as well. npm install --save webpack-dev-server@3.11.0  did the job.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. I think it's related to webpack version. After changing webpack version the latest everything was fine...

Comment: Also worth checking `webpack --version` from cli if you've got it installed globally.

Comment: Changing webpack to the latest causes this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937054/npm-run-dev-fails-validationerror-invalid-options-object

Comment: 2020 Update: downgrading to previous versions is not a very good solution, please checkout @serhii-matrunchyk answer below

Comment: This solution won't work for anyone who wants to use webpack-dev-server because it's not compatible with webpack 5. So what you need to do instead is uninstall existing webpack-cli version and then install webpack-cli version 3.3.8 with "npm install webpack-cli@3.3.8 -D". My webpack version is 4.44.2 and dev-server version is 3.11.0 if anyone's wondering.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268634/1112656

Comment: The answer below worked about using "webpack serve" instead of "webpack-dev-server"

Comment: Make sure `webpack`, `webpack-cli`, and `webpack-dev-server` are all up to date, and everything should be good.

Comment: @cwharris Apparently your comment has deemed the title of "unsung hero" as being the 6th most copied comment across all of StackOverflow while only having a score of 5 (scroll to the end): https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/

Answer (score 585):

If you're using **webpack-cli** 4 or **webpack 5**, change `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`.

Example:

```
"serve": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress"
```

You might want also check this [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2029#issuecomment-707196728) on GitHub:

> NPM `package.json` scripts are a convenient and useful means to run
> locally installed binaries without having to be concerned about their
> full paths. Simply define a script as such:
>
> For `webpack-cli 3.x`:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {   "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server" }
> ```
>
> For `webpack-cli 4.x`:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {   "start:dev": "webpack serve" }
> ```

Comment: Do you mean changing `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`?

Comment: Yes, if you are on webpack 4

Comment: I followed your suggeston but I am getting this ReferenceError:  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\testingWebpack\webpack.config.js:20:16).
The line 20 is:   plugins: new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" }), while the HtmlWebpackPlugin is actually defined at the top as:
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
So I do not understand what should I do.

Comment: @Lomono HtmlWebpackPlugin is something not relevant to the subject. Please ask a new question with the config you're using and feel free to post the link here.

Comment: this also works when combining webpack 5, webpack-cli 4 and webpack-dev-server 3 (the version treadmill never ends)

Comment: [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--watch'

Comment: Don't use `--watch` with `serve` it doesn't make any sense.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2401#issuecomment-772409309

Comment: This worked for me too, should be the accepted answer. webpack@^4.26.0 and webpack-cli@^4.5.0

Comment: ```
> webpack serve --config webpack.hot.config.js --progress

error: unknown option '--config'
```

Unknown option `—config` now.

Comment: You shall update `webpack-cli` as well. At least in my case.

Comment: Worked for me, I am sure these changes are made for fun to break your apps, I am sure they will rename it to something else again soon.

Comment: When I run `webpack serve` I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'serve'`, I think the API changed? I can bypass this issue with `concurrently --kill-others --raw \"webpack --watch --progress --colors --config webpack.config.js\" \"serve www\"` after installing _concurrently_ and _serve_.

Comment: Okay I found the solution, my project is still on Webpack 3 and I have to install `webpack-dev-server@2` and start it like so: `webpack-dev-server --watch --progress --colors --config webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 92):

**Jan 2021**

Using webpack 5, just replace the `webpack-dev-server` command with `webpack serve`

Comment: And also don't remove `webpack-dev-server`, `webpack serve` needs it.

Comment: Wait, it does work, but from their official [migration tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/), we get this: `serve is removed in favor of DevServer`. Is this really the recommended approach? Thanks.

Comment: @cbdeveloper apparently yes, according to webpack-dev-server [latest docs](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server#with-npm-scripts) as well.

Comment: I don't use webpack-dev-server as command, I use it in webpack.config. I have entry `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/'` but I have a same error

Comment: Tangential but if you are using Rails and `@rails/webpacker`, and you are OK with `webpack 4.x` for now, try `rails webpacker:install`. [details](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2905#issuecomment-792092215)

Answer (score 31):

**Update**: **March 21**

Try to **update** your webpack dependencies with the following command

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
```

if it does not work then use as following

I am having these dependencies but I faced the same issue

```
"webpack": "^5.6.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

And I found a **solution** that adding a new script or in your Start Script in **package.json** worked for me. So you can try this way as well.

`"dev": "webpack serve --mode development --env development"`

Comment: Your solution worked. Did you find out why webpack-dev-server is failing?

Comment: Could you just run ```yarn upgrade```

Answer (score 19):

This is because of the changes in `webpack-cli` version.

1. If the webpack-cli version is less than 4.x, You can use `webpack-dev-server`
2. If the webpack-cli version is 4.x or higher, you can use `webpack serve`

For `webpack-cli 3.x` and below

```json
    "scripts": {
      "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
    }
```

For `webpack-cli 4.x` and above

```json
    "scripts": {
      "dev-server": "webpack serve"
    }
```

```json
    "scripts": {
      "dev-server": "webpack serve "
    }
```

Source: [webpack dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

Comment: Unless you're using typescript for the config files, then it's easier to just use `webpack serve` for all 4.x and above.

Answer (score 14):

**Solution**

***package.json***

```
"scripts": {
    "startdev": "webpack serve --mode development --env development --hot --port 3000"
    ...
    ...
  },
"devDependencies": {
...
    "webpack": "^5.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
 },
```

**Console**

```
$ npm run startdev
```

Answer (score 11):

Try changing the webpack version from 1.x to 2.x in your package.json:

Eg:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-validator": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

This happens sometimes when you use pre-release version of `webpack-dev-server` with released version of `webpack` or viceversa.

Comment: It's Dec 2020, and I'm using `
        "webpack": "^4.44.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"`

Answer (score 11):

The issue is with newer webpack-cli version. If webpack-cli <= 3.x `webpack-dev-server` package work fine. For webpack-cli >= 4.x, use `npx webpack serve` command to run local server.

```
For webpack-cli 3.x:
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development"
}

For webpack-cli 4.x:
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "webpack serve --mode=development"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I forgot to install webpack-cli. So I ran below command and issue got fixed.

```
npm i -D webpack-cli
```

Answer (score 8):

Update your Webpack version (and webpack CLI):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server webpack-merge
```

If you don't use one of those mentioned above, feel free to omit.

Comment: This did it for me, thank you. Instead I ran yarn add (your command here) etc.

Answer (score 7):

I also go this error when I had only installed `webpack` locally and hadn't installed it globally yet.

I had `webpack-dev-server` installed globally though and it had a dependency on a global install of `webpack`. To be fair npm did complain while installing `webpack-dev-server`:

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@^2.2.0

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by creating a script command on **package.json**.

```
"dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open",
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the solution was just use previous versions -

```
"webpack": "^4.44.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar problem. I think it's related to webpack version.

**UPDATE JULY 2021**

People who have versions of `"webpack-cli": "^4 or above",` &  `"webpack": "^5 or above",`.

You can give a try updating your webpack version by this command

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
```

Now go to you `package.json`, under `scrpits` add this line

```
"dev": "webpack serve --mode development --env development"
```

This totally worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The general situation is due to Webpack and webpack-dev-server version is not compatible. 
Like I also have this problem, my computer's webpack is 1.15.0, but webpack-dev-server is 2.x above version. 
So I uninstall webpack-dev-server: npm uninstall webpack-dev-server -g 
Then install the 1.15.0 version of webpack-dev-server, you can solve this problem by  npm install webpack-dev-server@1.15.0 -g

Answer (score 4):

Try changing webpack version to 3.0 and web-dev-server to 2.7.1

Eg:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "2.0.13",
    "webpack-config-utils": "2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-validator": "2.2.7"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with webpack 4.

It is version compatible issue.

To fix the issue run following command to install webpack-cli in web pack 4 .

```
 yarn add webpack-cli -D
```

Answer (score 3):

Deprecate the webpack-cli version by using the command :

```
npm install -D webpack-cli@3
```

The new version is in the Beta phase and likely to fix this bug.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this solution by running `npm start` which was just a wrapper running 'webpack-dev-server' rather than running `webpack-dev-server` directly into the console.  The problem was that I was passing options into a method I should not have been passing options into.

Running `webpack-dev-server` with `npm start` showed me the correct error message.  Running `webpack-dev-server` directly only gave me "Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs' ".   Weird.

I am on:
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"

Answer (score 2):

I had got the following dependencies installed (without specifying any particular version)

```
 "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

This error appears during the `yarn start` with the following entry in `package.json` specific to the `scripts.start` attr.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
```

So, it turns out that `webpack-dev-server --open` is looking for  `webpack-cli` version `3.3`. I got rid of this error by installing the specific version of `webpack-cli` The working `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "webpack-cli": "3.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

But, if you don't want to downgrade the `webpack-cli` version, update the  `"start": "webpack-dev-server --open"` to `"start": "webpack serve --open"`

Comment: Can't believe this fixed it.  `"webpack": "^5.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"`

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to version mismatches between libraries (including webpack/yargs, in your case).  This can happen a lot when you have left a project sitting for a while and some dependencies in your node_modules directory have become stale.  A very simple solution, before fussing with different versions of everything, is to just move your node_modules directory to a temporary location and re-run npm install:

```
% mv node_modules nod_modules.REMOVED
% npm install
```

Then, try rerunning webpack.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade all packages (afer installing `webpack-cli` and `webpack-dev-server`), you can

```
npm --depth=9999 upgrade
```

That should fix the nonmatching version problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please use webpack serve for run webpack-dev-server

```
webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's webpack versioning problem
You need to update your webpack using this command

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
```

Now in package.json file use

```
"dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open"
```

Comment: webpack serve works, but my npm command requires a variable for some automatic things to be handled: `npm run start:front -- --page home` the --page home would determine which page to render. but when I do this with serve, it thinks it is an option

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following lines and it was solved:

1. As the issue is with webpack-dev-server so goto node-modules.
2. find webpack-dev-server then goto dependencies
3. check the dependency info of webpack and webpack-cli and their versions.
4. Reinstall those names with the exact same versions.

Then try re-running the dev-server.

In my case:
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --open"

console:
npm run dev-server

Answer (score 0):

-> So, first do you exclude the node_modules folder.
->after verificad if in the archive package.json the dependencies : "webpack", "webpack-cli" and "webpack-dev-server" they are in `"dependencies":{}`.
-> The end, Open the terminal execute the command : yarn. the install all depends again that was excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the command from `"serve": "webpack-dev-server"` to `"serve":"webpack serve"` solved this issue. I've tried this solution with `webpack dev server v3.11.0` and `v3.11.2`; both worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `webpack serve` instead of  `webpack-dev-server` in your package.json under `scripts`. it perfectly work for me. I had the same error and this fixed it.

my devDependencies:

```
"webpack": "^5.22.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

original post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64304022/11739552

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.

The problem was on **path** on **index.html**.

from:

```
<script src="./dist/myBundle.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="myBundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above answers worked for me. If you are still getting this error, you can try this, [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2029#issuecomment-544180366) fixed my problem:

> Open node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
>
> Change Line 84: require('webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs')(yargs);

To:

> require('webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs')(yargs);
>
> Change Line 92: const config =
>   require('webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv')(yargs, argv, {

To:

> const config = require('webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv')(yargs, argv, {

Answer (score -2):

downgrade webpack-cli

```
npm install -D webpack-cli@3
```