# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

'Github' asked me to update 'webpack-dev-server' to version 3.1.11 or higher for security reasons.

However, 'npm run dev' will not run after the update.

I don't solve this problem

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

The code for 'package.json' is as follows.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.1",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
```

Comment: Please excuse me for not putting all the codes because "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Which was your previous webpack-dev-server version?

Comment: Also how did you update the version?

Comment: It was 2.11.5. And what is the updated version? webpack-dev-server update?

Comment: 2.x.x -> 3.x.x is a [major](https://semver.org/) version update, so it may not be compatible with the rest of your dependencies. I suggest to review the vulnerability report and in case it's something minor or improbable to revert the update.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I agree that you have to upgrade from `webpack` 3 to 4, but specifically these are the steps I had to do, first, because `webpack-cli` has been split out into a separate package:

```
$ npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

As explained here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#basic-setup

Answer (score 170):

You could try changing `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve` in your npm run script inside package.json

Comment: This is a useful answer particular when your project has these versions
    `webpack": "^5.2.0`
   `webpack-cli": "^4.1.0`
   `webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0`

Comment: I had the same issue and I coudnt find a way to solve it... but, this is the perfect answer... and as @Mark said... Works perfect for the versions he mentioned above... 
Thank you.

Comment: This answer saved me! THANKS.

Comment: I got above error message with rails 6 and yarn. My package.json doesn't have a script command inside. Do you @Gakis41 may know how to handle this?

Comment: @Phipsen can you share your package.json? Do you have webpack & webpack-cli installed in devDependencies?

Comment: @Gakis41: I finally found out, that adding coffeescript module was causing all these problems. I set up a new rails project and added the modules one by one. At the coffeescript and coffee-loader module, it failed. In Rails 6, I still start with webpack-dev-server, and this works. I have these versions on package.json: `"@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.2.2", "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"`. I migrated the coffeescripts back to js. Not sure whether coffeescript will survive..

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER! Yes, I struggled with package versions, npm logs only to find out that this actually is the cause.

Comment: This answer is more aligned with Webpack official documentation.

Comment: This answer works for me, and I just install Webpack recently, better vote correct for future references

Answer (score 35):

For some reason the webpack team changed the command to `webpack serve`
Change your package.json:

`"start": "webpack serve"`

Ref: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759

The version I am using:

```
"webpack": "^5.10.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

Answer (score 21):

To fix it just do 2 things.

1. Install
   `npm i webpack-cli @webpack-cli/init`
2. Add this to your package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "webpack-cli serve --mode development"
   },
   ```

Done!

Comment: Thanks for help, I follow all things and many blogs but this work for me. Please add some expansion.

Answer (score 17):

Delete package-lock.json file. Change following in package.json.

```
"webpack": "^4.32.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

Run npm install

Answer (score 16):

Change `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve` in  **package.json** file.

e.g.:

> "scripts": { "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open" },

It worked for me! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Run: `npm run start or npm start now`

Answer (score 3):

It is because of version of webpack-cli. In some versions, there is no config-yargs.js file. So `^3.3.11` version of webpack-cli worked for me.
Try it:

`npm i webpack-cli@^3.3.11`

Answer (score 1):

webpack core team says that [form version 3+](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.1) the compatibility will foucs on webpack 4

so I think you need also to update webpack 3 to webpack 4

this doc may help you to achieve that 
https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4

Comment: I already solve this problem, but thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check to find out the latest versions of webpack, webpack-cli and webpack-dev-server and when you have that information edit package.json to reflect those versions and run yarn install --check-files Then you'll have to start the webpack-dev-server with the command "npx webpack serve"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **package.json** file line : `webpack-cli@4.10.0`

Then run below commands in terminal: It has worked for me.

1. `npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0`
2. `npm install --save-dev webpack-cl`