# npm run dev fails : ValidationError: Invalid options object

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack-dev-server, webpack-cli

Currently learning Vue js and express js through some tutorials, I am still newbie regarding these technologies.

Anyway following the tutorials I am building a small project in which I have a folder "Client" that contains the frontend side of the project and another folder "Server" that contains the backend.

Just before pushing commits to Github, everything was fine, but once I did Github signals some vulnerabilities and after fixing them npm run dev doesn't work anymore.

tried multiples solutions but nothing worked, reinstalled suspicious modules, reinstalled node modules after running *npm cache clean --force*

This is the error I got

```
   npm run dev


> client@1.0.0 dev D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:88
    throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
    ^

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
    at validate (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:88:11)  
    at new CopyPlugin (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:24:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\build\webpack.dev.conf.js:61:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:84:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30) {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'required',
      dataPath: '[0]',
      schemaPath: '#/required',
      params: [Object],
      message: "should have required property 'patterns'",
      schema: [Object],
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Object],
      children: [Array]
    }
  ],
  schema: {
    definitions: { ObjectPattern: [Object], StringPattern: [Object] },
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: { patterns: [Object], options: [Object] },
    required: [ 'patterns' ]
  },
  headerName: 'Copy Plugin',
  baseDataPath: 'options',
  postFormatter: null
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\iheb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T13_56_52_099Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\iheb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T13_56_52_148Z-debug.log
```

This is the log file :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build:server'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build:server
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:281:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
5 verbose cwd D:\projects\Fullstack web apps\VueJs ExpressJs\tab-tracker\Client
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build:server"
8 verbose node v12.16.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.4
10 error missing script: build:server
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Running *npm audit* gives the following :

> ```
>     Moderate        Cross-Site Scripting                                          
>
>   Package         serialize-javascript                                          
>
>   Patched in      >=2.1.1                                                       
>
>   Dependency of   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin [dev]                                 
>
>   Path            uglifyjs-webpack-plugin > serialize-javascript                
>
>   More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426
> ```

Related dependencies

> "webpack": "^4.43.0",
>
> ```
> "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
>
> "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
>
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.11",
> ```

I hope I provided everything for you guys, if not I will immediately provide anything to help clarify my problem, as I said I'm a newbie to web development.

**UPDATE:** I've trying to figure out the reason behind such error, the problem occurs after updating **webpack-dev-server**
Version that works :

> "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"

Version with errors :

> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"

Is it okay if I ignore vulnerabilities found? Because trying to fix them causes this error.

Thanks

Comment: Webpack 5 has major changes, this article helped me https://frontendguruji.com/blog/invalid-options-object-dev-server/

Answer (score 139):

This is not an issue with `webpack` or `webpack-dev-server` itself, but with the  `copy-webpack-plugin` plugin.

With the update to the 6.x major version came a breaking change: instead of just passing the array with the config patterns directly to the `CopyWebpackPlugin` constructor, your now have to wrap it in the `patterns` property of an object and pass that.

Old syntax:

```js
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      [
        { from: 'src/xxx.ext', to: 'dist/xxx.ext' },
        { from: 'src/yyy.ext', to: 'dist/yyy.ext' }
      ]
    )
```

New syntax:

```js
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      { 
        patterns: [
          { from: 'src/xxx.ext', to: 'dist/xxx.ext' },
          { from: 'src/yyy.ext', to: 'dist/yyy.ext' }
        ]
      }
    )
```

They did that because the constructor now supports an additional `options` property:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#options-1

Comment: Tried to get it work for a outlook add-in --> this here is the solution.

Comment: For me, my predecessors used webpack.mix.js as the configuration file. Copy Webpack was not referenced directly but through mix.imagemin where I used this:
<pre><code>
mix.imagemin([{
  patterns: [{
    from: '**/*{.png,.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.svg}',
    to: 'images/',
    context: 'src/images/'
  }, {
    from: '**/*{.png,.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.svg}',
    to: 'images/',
    context: 'src/components/'
  }]
}]);
</code></pre>

Answer (score 47):

After updating to 3.11 a new template appeared

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'source', to: 'dest' },
        { from: 'other', to: 'public' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: meaning that I should add the following code? if yes then where to add it 
I am completely new to node

Comment: Yes, I mean it. 
File > webpack.config.js
    module.exports = { }

Comment: Should I replace CopyPlugin with webpack-dev-server or not ?

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

After in "plugins:"

new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/fonts'),
          to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/fonts')
        }
      ]
    }),

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Finally, I was able to solve it using

```sh
npm install --save copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.1
```

Answer (score 6):

If you upgrade to copy-webpack-plugin: ^6.0.3 in your package.json then following should work, when you previously copied a whole directory:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {
                from: "[your-src-dir]/*",
                to: "[your-dst-dir]/*",
            },
        ],
    }),
]
```

adding /* after directory target and source directory name fixed it without ignoring vulnerability, which you should never do.

Take a look at https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ for more.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me

at webpack.config.js file change the **CopyWebpackPlugin**

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                  { from: "fonts/**", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
                  { from: "**/*.{jpg,png}", globOptions: { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] } },
                ]
              }),
```

hope I help

Answer (score 0):

Reset angular toolkit version to 2.3.0 using the below command.

```
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.3.0 -E -D
```