# yarn build. Error - Invalid options object

Tags: yarnpkg, webpack-5

I learn  React and try to build my own setup of webpack5 + babel and I have this error message in my console after run `yarn build`. Any ideas on how to fix that or what I did wrong?

```
Failed to load '/Users/admin/webpackFuel/webpack.config.js' config  Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:    [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, filter?, toType?, force?, info?, transform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm run dev fails : ValidationError: Invalid options object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937054/npm-run-dev-fails-validationerror-invalid-options-object)

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in this tread - [npm run dev fails : ValidationError: Invalid options object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937054/npm-run-dev-fails-validationerror-invalid-options-object)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62680933 - there it is. Totally forget about the word "patterns"