# Yarn start - Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm having a little problem while trying to run "Yarn start" in my ReactJS project.
The error is pasted below:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ webpack-dev-server --mode development
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI
-> When using npm: npm i -D webpack-cli
-> When using yarn: yarn add -D webpack-cli
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\3AM\web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\3AM\web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\3AM\\web\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried to install webpack-dev-server with npm and yarn, but it didn't solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379139/cannot-find-module-webpack-bin-config-yargs)

Answer (score 0):

In package.json change the start script to `"start": "webpack serve"`.