# unable to fix the Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: reactjs

here is my package.json installed package while setup.
while setup new application it say this error.
its new react application and all the versions are latest.

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/infinitydots-cn/front-end.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/infinitydots-cn/front-end/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/infinitydots-cn/front-end#readme",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.22.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379139/cannot-find-module-webpack-bin-config-yargs)