# i keep getting this error when i start the code below

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

C:\Users\georg\Desktop\reactapp>npm start

> reactapp@1.0.0 start
> webpack-dev-server --hot

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\georg\Desktop\reactapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\reactapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\georg\Desktop\reactapp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
  }

this is the error above.

{
"name": "reactapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Individual Project",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
},
"keywords": [
"npm",
"Individual",
"project"
],
"author": "George Ashinze",
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"webpack": "^5.38.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
}

}
this is my package.json file above

Comment: Have you ran `npm install`?

Comment: yes i have ran that

Comment: Would recommend you to delete node_modules folder and package.lock.json and install again

Comment: yes i started all over again earlier and ended up getting the same error, i do not know where i went wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379139/cannot-find-module-webpack-bin-config-yargs)

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions are

- update your webpack version,
  OR
  If you're using webpack-cli 4 or webpack 5, change webpack-dev-server to webpack serve.

Example:

```
"serve": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress"
```

Comment: i am using "webpack": "^5.38.1"

Comment: [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. this is what happens when i use webpack serve