# Webpack. Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have problems.
I tried to change `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`, but it didn't help. also tried to prescribe it separately: `"start": "webpack serve"`. It also didn't help...

Terminal error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Maryana\Desktop\zeta\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maryana\Desktop\zeta\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Maryana\\Desktop\\zeta\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zeta@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Maryana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-24T14_32_15_253Z-debug.log
```

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config ./build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./build/webpack.build.conf.js"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 3 version"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
```

---

Maybe someone will need to change devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' to devtool: 'eval-source-map'

Answer (score 0):

try this answer

[Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379139/cannot-find-module-webpack-bin-config-yargs)

> You can give a try updating your webpack version by this command
>
> `npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server`
> Now go to you package.json, under scrpits add this line
>
> `"dev": "webpack serve --mode development --env development"`

> Also worth checking webpack --version from cli if you've got it installed globally.